# Grab Email Address from Long Text Area Field

Tags: before-trigger

We would like to pull an email address from the standard Description field on Case and populate it in a custom field.

Description field example: *Customer's email address is smile@gmail.com.  Please contact within 24 hours.*

We would like *smile@gmail.com* to be populated into another field (i.e. CaseEmailAddress_c).

These particular cases are created when we receive an email from a "no reply" account and thus have no contact or account related to them.

I don't think a formula would work.  And I've played around with the following trigger with no success:

> ```
> trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update) {
> for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
>     if (c.Description != null) {
>         Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile('(?i)^([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4})$');
>         Boolean foundEmailMatch = false;
>         
>         for (String bit: c.Description.split(' ')) {
>             Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(bit);
>             if (emailMatcher.matches()) {
>                 foundEmailMatch = true;
>                 c.CaseEmailAddress_c = bit;
>             }
>         }
>         
>         if (!foundEmailMatch) {
>             c.CaseEmailAddress_c = null;
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

Any ideas of how we can achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are correct that a formula will not work as REGEX can't be used on text area long fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a solution like this to pull the email address and also the ContactId for later use, based on the email address. Assuming the email address is on a contact record in your org. You may also want to add some type of filtering to make sure this trigger only tries to do this operation when it is coming from the email to case with a certain email address.

```
    trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update) {
    for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
        if (c.Description != null) {
            List<String> lines = new List<String>();
            lines = c.Description.split('\n');
            
            for (String line: lines) {
                if(line.contains('Email Address: ')){
                    line.remove('Email Address: ');
                    system.debug(line);
                    c.CaseEmailAddress_c = line;
                }
            }
            if(c.CaseEmailAddress_c !=null){
                List<Contact> cons = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email=:c.CaseEmailAddress_c LIMIT 1];
                if(cons.size()>0)c.ContactId=cons[0];
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher! This worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

your regex is not working as there is a full stop (.)  after email.  you have to remove full stop before matching.

answer i have referred to removed full stop  regex:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477732/removing-full-stops-from-string

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update) {
for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
    if (c.Description != null) {
      //remove full stop from description
string description = c.Description.replaceAll('\\.(?=\\s|$)', '');

        Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile('(?i)^([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4})$');
        Boolean foundEmailMatch = false;
        
        for (String bit: description.split(' ')) {
            Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(bit);
            if (emailMatcher.matches()) {
                foundEmailMatch = true;
                c.CaseEmailAddress_c = bit;
            }
        }
        
        if (!foundEmailMatch) {
            c.CaseEmailAddress_c = null;
        }
    }
} }
```

Comment: Does the field type (CaseEmailAddress__c) matter?  I'm currently using an email field.

Comment: Hope it should not matter.   to full confirm   can you system.debug   bit in   if (emailMatcher.matches()) {
                foundEmailMatch = true;
                c.CaseEmailAddress_c = bit;
            }    and check   if you are getting your email.

Comment: It's not populating the field with anything.  :/ I'm unable to do a system debug right now, but will definitely try later.  Thank you so much for your all of your help!